# Unique values by date

Tags: r, match, unique

I would like to obtain a data frame that contains two columns: 1. The different fruits (no duplicates) 2. The first date of the appearance of the specific fruit (i.e. kiwis)

```
fruits <- c("apples, oranges, pears, bananas",
"pineapples, mangos, guavas",
"bananas, apples, kiwis") 


fruits<-as.data.frame(fruits)
fruits$date<-c( "12.8.16", "22.4.17", "12.9.16")

fruits[with(fruits, order(date)), ]
```

I tried to write a loop or use the match command. However, the unique string values are not recognized.

Thank you in advance!
Jannis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some solutions:

**1) strsplit/unnest/summarize** This uses dplyr and tidyr.  First convert `date` column to `"Date"` class and split the `fruits` column producing a column where each cell contains a vector of fruits.  `unnest` that and find the minimums:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fruits %>%
       mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d.%m.%y"),
              fruits = strsplit(as.character(fruits), ", ")) %>%
       unnest %>%
       group_by(fruits) %>%
       summarize(date = min(date)) %>%
       ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
      fruits       date
       <chr>     <date>
1     apples 2016-08-12
2    bananas 2016-08-12
3     guavas 2017-04-22
4      kiwis 2016-09-12
5     mangos 2017-04-22
6    oranges 2016-08-12
7      pears 2016-08-12
8 pineapples 2017-04-22
```

**1a) separate_rows/summarize** This slightly shorter variation uses `separate_rows` (replacing the `strsplit` and `unnest` lines with a single simpler command).  It requires tidyr 0.5 or later.  It gives the same result:

```
fruits %>%
       mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d.%m.%y")) %>%
       separate_rows(fruits) %>%
       group_by(fruits) %>%
       summarize(date = min(date)) %>%
       ungroup
```

**2) strsplit/stack/aggregate** This does not use any packages.  First we split the fruits column and name the components of the resulting list, `L`, with dates.  Then we stack the list creating a data frame and rename the columns while also creating a true `"Date"` class column.  Finally we `aggregate` to find the minimums.

```
L <- with(fruits, setNames(strsplit(as.character(fruits), ", "), as.Date(date,"%d.%m.%y")))
stk <- with(stack(L), data.frame(fruits = values, date = as.Date(ind)))
aggregate(date ~ fruits, stk, min)
```

giving this data.frame:

```
      fruits       date
1     apples 2016-08-12
2    bananas 2016-08-12
3     guavas 2017-04-22
4      kiwis 2016-09-12
5     mangos 2017-04-22
6    oranges 2016-08-12
7      pears 2016-08-12
8 pineapples 2017-04-22
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using the *splitstackshape* package, which uses the *data.table* package underneath.  We can use `cSplit()` to split the `fruits` column at the comma, then use *data.table* syntax to take the minimum `date`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
## create the long data frame from the split 'fruits' column
DT <- cSplit(fruits, "fruits", sep = ",", direction = "long")
## convert the 'date' column to date class and take the minimum row
DT[, .(date = min(as.IDate(date, "%d.%m.%y"))), by = fruits]
#        fruits       date
# 1:     apples 2016-08-12
# 2:    oranges 2016-08-12
# 3:      pears 2016-08-12
# 4:    bananas 2016-08-12
# 5: pineapples 2017-04-22
# 6:     mangos 2017-04-22
# 7:     guavas 2017-04-22
# 8:      kiwis 2016-09-12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.

```
fruits <- c("apples, oranges, pears, bananas",
        "pineapples, mangos, guavas",
        "bananas, apples, kiwis") 

fruits<-as.data.frame(fruits,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) #probably easier for the fruits to be strings rather than factors
fruits$date<-as.Date(c( "12.8.16", "22.4.17", "12.9.16"),format="%d.%m.%y") #and set your dates to be Dates rather than strings (otherwise they will be sorted alphabetically)

fruits[with(fruits, order(date)), ]

#need to convert your df to one-fruit-per-row
fruits2 <- do.call(rbind, #this binds together the data frames created by the lapply loop
               lapply(1:nrow(fruits), #loops through the rows of fruits df to create a list of data frames, each corresponding to one row
                      function(i) data.frame(fruit=trimws(strsplit((fruits$fruits),",")[[i]]), #splits your strings at commas, and trims off the whitespace
                                             date=fruits$date[i],stringsAsFactors = FALSE))) #adds the date corresponding to each row

#finding the first appearance is easily done using dplyr
library(dplyr)
fruits3 <- fruits2 %>% group_by(fruit) %>% summarise(firstdate=min(date))
```

Or another approach would be to set up a data frame using the unique names of the fruits, and then find the first date using a `grep` lookup for each fruit...

```
fruits <- fruits[order(fruits$date),]
firstfruits <- data.frame(fruit=unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(fruits$fruits,",")))),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
firstfruits$date <- do.call(c,lapply(firstfruits$fruit, function(F) fruits$date[grep(F,fruits$fruits)[1]]))
```